# Listen to the changes in subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I wonder if it's possible to subscribe the the whole collection of the document in the way that if any child node (even deep nested like `completness.energy` values inside `2020.2.1`) inside the `balanceRecords` gets change the listener trigger

I've tried:

```
FirebaseDb.collection(`users`).doc(uid).collection(`balanceRecords`)
  .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, function (snapshot) {
    debugger
    // during initialisation snapshot:
    // docs.length = 0 
    // empty: true
})
```

Subsequent updates of the collection don't trigger any listener can you please if there is valid approach to listen fields of documents sub-collection?

Comment: The listener you attach should fire for any changes under the `balanceRecords` subcollection for the user identified by `uid`. If that isn't happening for  you, please update your question to show how you change that document. It might at that point also be helpful if you can set up a reproduction of the problem on a site like jsbin, so that we can have a look.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Unfortunately, from the screenshot provided, they do not have a balanceRecords subcollection.  They have a balanceRecords field in a document.

Comment: Ah, got it! That's indeed not possible, unless OP puts the balances in yet another subcollection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227376/firestore-listener-for-sub-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you provided shows a single document with no subcollections.  The document has a single field visible called "balanceRecords" which contains a complex-looking object.  Since it's not a subcollection, you can **not** refer to it using the code you wrote.

If you want to read that field, you have to read the named document. If you want to listener to changes in that field, you will have to set up a snapshot listener on that single document.  The snapshot listener will not tell you exactly what changed in that field - you will have to compare it to the previous snapshot to find that out.

```
FirebaseDb.collection('users').doc(uid).onSnapshot(snapshot -> {
    // read the balanceRecords field out of the document here.
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Doug, this indeed works, but it returns `DocumentReference` which from what I understood doesn't allow to see what was actually change `.docChanges()` so I was wondering if it's possible to subscribe in a way have a possibility to see the changes :-)

Comment: As I said in my answer, that's not provided by the SDK.  You have to write code to compare the the prior snapshot with the new one to see if anything changed with any of the fields.

Comment: I see, from the comment of Frank it appears that there is a possibility to listen a sub-collection of documents collection in case of the screen shot it's the field 2020. Is it indeed somehow possible? :)

Comment: You would have to completely restructure your data to use a subcollection instead.

Comment: Can you please provide an example as a food for thoughts :-)

Comment: I don't know what the needs of your app are, so I suggest you make an attempt that meets your own needs, and post a new question here again here if you have trouble.

Comment: After a proper sleep I finally understood that I was using a document fields instead of actual sub-collection. Thank you for the support Doug :smile: